# Content Security Policy Endpoint cspreport not found POST https://localhost:44331/cspreport returns 404 Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, content-security-policy, endpoint, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to add Content Security Policy reporting and for that I've followed [this](https://dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-content-security-policy-in-aspnetcore/) along.

My `CspReportRequest` class is:

```
public class CspReportRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("csp-report")]
    public CspReport CspReport { get; set; }
}

public class CspReport
{
    [JsonPropertyName("document-uri")]
    public string DocumentUri { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("referrer")]
    public string Referrer { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("violated-directive")]
    public string ViolatedDirective { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("effective-directive")]
    public string EffectiveDirective { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("original-policy")]
    public string OriginalPolicy { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("blocked-uri")]
    public string BlockedUri { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("status-code")]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

In my `HomeController` I have:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/cspreport")]
    public IActionResult CSPReport([FromBody] CspReportRequest cspReportRequest)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cspReportRequest);
        return Ok();
    }
```

And to avoid 415 errors I've also implemented

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            var jsonInputFormatter = options.InputFormatters
                .OfType<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>()
                .Single();

            jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/csp-report");
        });
```

My `context.Response.Headers`, simplified for brevity:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add(
"Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only",
"default-src 'self' ;" +
"script-src-elem 'self' ;" +
"script-src 'self' ;" +
"style-src-elem 'self' ;" +
"img-src 'self' " +
"font-src 'self' " +
"media-src 'self'  ;" +
"frame-src 'self' ;" +
"connect-src 'self' " +
"object-src 'none' ;" +
"base-uri 'self' ;" +
"report-uri /cspreport ;"
);
```

My problem is that I see the CSP Request using the developers tools but with a 404 error. If I try with Postman I get the same error as well.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL in not correct,if you did not change the default route settings,the correct URL should be `https://localhost:44331/Home/Cspreport`

you could read the document related :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-template-reference

Comment: Hi Ruikai, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I've added up the following lines of code: app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>             {                 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(                     name: "default",                     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");                 endpoints.MapPost("/cspreport", async context =>                 {                     await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only"]);                 });                 endpoints.MapRazorPages();